# WPF Resource not reflecting changes from code behind

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization

In MainWindow...

```
Ingredients allIngredients = this.FindResource("allIngredients") as Ingredients;
allIngredients = (Ingredients)reader.Deserialize(file);
foreach (Ingredient i in allIngredients)
{
  ingredientListBox.Items.Add(i);
}
```

The XML deserializes into my object fine, the listbox populates with the items just fine.  However, I also need to be able to access allIngredients from another method inside MainWindow, and when I do another FindResource in that method, all I have is an empty list.  I've done testing with other FindResource situations, and in those situations the resource reflected any changes made, no matter what method I changed them from.  This seems to only happen when I deserialize into the resource.  The object becomes populated and works as expected, but only in the method that I deserialize in.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you don't change the instance that's saved in the resource dictionary, but instead **create a new object** (by deserializing) and don't save it into the dictionary.

Here's how you should do it (note you don't even need to read from the dictionary):

```
var allIngredients = (Ingredients)reader.Deserialize(file);
element.Resources["allIngredients"] = allIngredients;
foreach (Ingredient i in allIngredients)
{
  ingredientListBox.Items.Add(i);
}
```

This assumes `element` is where the resource is found (possibly be `this` in your code.)

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed.  Thanks!  I tried `this.FindResource("allIngredients") = allIngredients` but that didn't work.